# Determining if the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0+)} x \ln y$ exists

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I am having trouble determining if the limit 
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0+)} x \ln y$$ 
exists. 
I tried using the path $y=kx^n$, but this gives us nothing:
$$\lim_{x\to 0} x \ln kx^n=\lim_{x\to 0} x (\ln k+n\ln x)
=n\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln x}{1/x}$$
$$
=n\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1/x}{-1/x^2}=0;$$ 
this does not imply that the limit exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit does not exist.  Counterexample: let $x=\frac{1}{ln(y)}$ then  $xln(y)=1$ for all $(x,y)$.